# Export data from a file into Excel Python 2.7

Tags: excel, python-2.7, loops

I would need to create an Excel sheet out of a file. The file has this format, but has dozens of templates like this one. To match the representation of my entire file, the following format can be copy pasted twice:

```
 Field                                 Value                                                                                                          
 OS-DCF:diskConfig                     MANUAL                                                                                                     
 OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone           az1                                                                                                        
 OS-EXT-STS:power_state                1                                                                                                          
 OS-EXT-STS:task_state                 None                                                                                                       
 OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                   active                                                                                                     
 OS-SRV-USG:launched_at                2016-02-04T12:53:35.000000                                                                                 
 OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at              None                                                                                                       
 accessIPv4                                                                                                                                       
 accessIPv6                                                                                                                                       
 addresses                             10.10.10.10                                                                                                
 config_drive                          True                                                                                                       
 created                               2018-09-04T12:52:52Z                                                                                       
 flavor                                m1.small                                                                                                   
 hostId                                ajsdajdad-qweqweqw-qwe123123-qweqweq-sadsadasd-1121212                                                     
 id                                    922adwq-qwejjqeq-123123-asdasa                                                                             
 image                                 cirros1                                                                                                    
 key_name                              None                                                                                                       
 name                                  vm1                                                                                                        
 os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached  []                                                                                                         
 progress                              0                                                                                                          
 project_id                            id                                                                                                         
 properties                            ctrl='10.10.10.3', token='token', tenant='tenant1'                                                         
 scheduler_hints                       {}                                                                                                         
 security_groups                       [{u'name': u'sg1'}, {u'name': u'sg2'}]                                                                     
 status                                ACTIVE                                                                                                     
 updated                               2016-02-04T12:53:35Z                                                                                       
 user_id                               user1
```

The Excel file should look like this:

[image: Excel]

The problematic part seems to be here:

```
hostname, chains_segment = host.split('\n',1)
hostname = hostname.strip()
```

After the strip, I should get the VM name value, but I am getting empty values.

Here is the full code:

```
import xlsxwriter
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Script")
parser.add_argument('-i','--input',help='Input log file name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o','--output',help='Desired name for the Excel file',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-s','--sheet',help='Desired name of the Excel sheet(Default: Sheet1)',default='Sheet1',required=False)
args=parser.parse_args()

az='| OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone          | '
state='| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                  | '
launch='| OS-SRV-USG:launched_at               | '
ipaddr='| addresses                            | '
flavor='| flavor                               | '
image='| image                                | '

def create_chain(chain_segment):
    chains=[]
    chain_lines = [line for line in chain_segment.split('\n') if line]
    for line in chain_lines:
        chain={}
        if launch in line:
           chain['launch'] = line.split()[3]
        #      chain['az'] = line.split()[3] 
        #      chain['state'] = line.split()[3]
        #      chain['ipaddr'] = line.split()[3]
        #      chain['flavor'] = line.split()[3]
        #      chain['image'] = line.split()[3]
        chains.append(chain)       
        chains=filter(None, chains)
    chains=list(chains)
    chained = [merge_dicts(chains[0], i) for i in chains[1:]]
    return chained

def merge_dicts(x,y):
   z=x.copy()
   z.update(y)
   return z

with open(args.input) as f:
    log_content = f.read()

host_sections = [host for host in log_content.split(" Field                                 Value") if host]
hosts = {}

for host in host_sections:
    hostname, chains_segment = host.split('\n',1)
    hostname = hostname.strip()
    chains=[]
    for segment in chains_segment.split('\n\n'):
            chains.extend(create_chain(segment))
    hosts[hostname] = chains

workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook(args.output)
worksheet1=workbook.add_worksheet(args.sheet)

worksheet1.write(0,0,'VM')
worksheet1.write(0,1,'Availability Zone')
worksheet1.write(0,2,'State')
worksheet1.write(0,3,'Launched at')
worksheet1.write(0,4,'IP Address')
worksheet1.write(0,5,'Flavor')
worksheet1.write(0,6,'Image')
worksheet1.write(0,7,'Tenant')
worksheet1.write(0,8,'Security Group')
row = 1

for host, chains in hosts.items():
    for chain in chains:
        worksheet1.write(row, 0, host)
        worksheet1.write(row, 1, chain.get('az'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 2, chain.get('state'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 3, chain.get('launch'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 4, chain.get('ipaddr'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 5, chain.get('flavor'))
        worksheet1.write(row, 6, chain.get('image'))
        row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Any idea how I can correct this?

Many thanks,

Albert

**P.S. Please note that I am new to programming.**

Comment: First of all, establish whether the problem is in your code to read the data from the source files or in the code to write this data to the Excel file. Inspect what you're getting in `hosts` and check if it's exactly what you intended. Then you can ask a more focused question showing the smaller section of code that is going wrong, the input data you're giving it, the output you get and the expected output.

Comment: @nekomatic: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to isolate the problem as much as possible.